# Speeding up re.sub in python

Tags: python

I have the following Python code, but its running a bit slow on a 10mb file. I'm wondering is there any way to speed it up? Maybe by doing the re.sub all in one go (rather than two operations) - not sure how to do this though, or maybe there is another way?

```
def ChangeMode(file, amode0, amode1, bmode0, bmode1):
for line in iter(file):
    if 'AAA' in line or 'BBB' in line or 'CCC' in line:
            line = re.sub(mode0, mode1, line)
            line = re.sub(bmode0, bmode1, line)
    endstring += line
return endstring
```

Cheers

Comment: You can pre-compile the pattern using `re.compile` and pass the compiled pattern to `re.sub`.

Comment: compile the regex first, looking at `for line in iter(file)` makes me think you might not need a regex at all, what do you think iter is doing?

Comment: Hi, Im wondering how to do that in the context of my function? Any ideas? I'm new to all of this...

Comment: Show some content and what you are trying to do with it

Comment: @micgeronimo wouldn't that match `ABC` as well? `r'(AAA|BBB|CCC)'` may be what you intend.

Comment: Please double check your question: there are arguments `amode0` and `amode1` in the function definition, yet in the first `re.sub` line there is `mode0` and `mode1`.

Comment: @Evert, no if he needs three letters to match this is shortest I think. What you offer is bad because when you will need to match 100 combinations your expression will be long as hell

Comment: @micgeronimo where do you get 100 combinations from? And my point is about the string `'ABC'`, which your regex seems to match. But: the matches in the `if` statement are a condition, and may not be the actual regex anyway.

Comment: @Evert, need to edit this a bit, but any way I meant that bad idea to repeat one letter three times in regular expression, because if you will want to match D,E,F,G, expression will become longer

Comment: If this is slow, the likely culprits are bad regular expressions. Show us some sample values for `mode0` and `bmode0`.

Comment: Just an idea: if you know an upper bound for the number of expected substitutions, pass it to `count` ([doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub)). In my case it made a huge difference (huge byte array, 1 match expected, always near the beginning of the array).

Answer (score 2):

If the affected lines are rare you can speed up a lot by using `re.sub` or `re.finditer` for finding those lines directly instead of iterating over the lines at Python level. And `str.replace` is fast in case of simple string replacements:

```
def fsub(m):
    return m.group().replace('ij', 'xx').replace('kl', 'yy')

s = re.sub('(?m)^.*(?:AAA|BBB|CCC).*', fsub, open(path).read())
```

Note: `(?m)` causes the `^` to match the beginning of each line and `.*` to not grab beyond line end.

REGEX pre-compilation can speed up many individual REGEX re.sub's (when simple string replacements are not applicable) a little:

```
rec = re.compile(r'ij\d+') # once
...
line = rec.sub('xx', line)  # often
```

(`re.sub` however uses already a REGEX compile cache which is quite fast yet.)

If the replacements do not change the string size, you can speed up things a lot by using `bytearray` / buffers or even `mmap` and modify the data in-place. (`re.sub()` and `string.replace` and `endstring += line` cause that a lot of memory is copyied around.)